# XMLNODELIST to GenericList and Split

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a `XMLNODELIST` `nodees`. I'm trying to convert this to GenericList and extracting some attributes at the same time. The following code is working. But I'm having issue's with splitting the `fieldName`. It comes in the format: `Left Team Title:Text:`.

I need the string `Left Team Title` and want to put the Text as a separate value in the list under `Text` as shown in the code below:

```
var productDetails = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => new {
field = (String)x.Attributes["userName"].Value,
fieldName = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Split(':'),
Text = //TEXT should go here
});
```

I'm getting error on `.Split` as below

> ERROR:`Cannot convert type 'string[]' to 'string'`

How do I go about achieving this.

Comment: I want to do this using linq.

Comment: I have got this to answer my self, would be glad if this can be reopened so I can post the answer which can help other

Comment: Here's the answer hope it helps someone who is struggling with the same issue: `            var templateFields = nodees.Cast<XmlNode>()   .Select(x => new {
    field = (String)x.Attributes["userName"].Value,
    fieldName = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(0,x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':')),
    type = (String)x.Attributes["name"].Value.Substring(x.Attributes["name"].Value.IndexOf(':')+1,4)
    
});`